# ¿Como unir dos consultas independientes en una sola tabla?

Tags: sql

Hola buenas tengo una pequeña consulta y es que quiero unir dos consultas que no tienen nada que ver entre si, en una sola tabla, por ejemplo, tengo la tabla empleado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y tengo una segunda tabla llamada pais[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
lo que quiero es unir la tabla empleado con la tabla pais, osea que los datos de pais me salgan en nuevas columnas pero dentro de la misma tabla, el resultado seria
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que la pregunta está mal planteada. Si quieres unir las tablas es porque tiene algo que ver, pues de lo contrario, ¿para qué querrías unirlas? Dicho eso, ¿qué tienen que ver? pues yo veo que **las tablas se relacionan por el campo `id`**, supongo que quieres unir las filas por ese campo, ¿estoy en lo cierto o no? Debes aclarar ese punto para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Por favor tu código y tablas como texto y no como imagen

Comment: @A.Cedano, lo que pasa es que necesito hacer un reporte con reportviewer en c# y solo puedo mostrar una consulta a la vez, es por eso que necesito poder obtener estas dos consultas en una sola y de esta manera poder capturarlas desde mi reportViewer en C#

Comment: Ya, pero quise rebatir tu planteamiento porque es erróneo y puede tener consecuencias para el rendimiento de tu aplicación. No puedes pensar que *estas dos tablas no tienen nada que ver*, porque sí tienen que ver. El sentido de la relación sería que, por el `id` se supiera el país de nacimiento de la persona por ejemplo. Los que tengan `id=1` nacieron en `EE.UU`, etc. Eso significa que necesitarás índices y relaciones entre esas dos tablas y especificar bien las columnas de la relación, pues otro problema es que en la 1ª tabla ese `id` podría ser la llave primaria y necesitaría un `id_pais`

Comment: Creo entender que quieres ver los campos de las dos tablas en una sola consulta, pero no tienen relación alguna entre ellas. En ese caso, la respuesta de Jeansanchezr es lo apropiado, pero para nada correcto, pues no es normal mezclar reportes o informes de tablas que no tienen nada que ver entre sí. Tal vez deberías preguntar ¿cómo puedo sacar dos informes de reportviewer en c# con solo una consulta? así tal vez alguien sepa la forma de hacerlo correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Si no hay ningun tipo de relacion como es que las piensas unir? 
en tu ejemplo parece haber coincidencia con los IDS, puedes usar un JOIN para mostrarlas en tu consulta,

```
 select * 
from empleado as e
left join pais as p on e.id = p.id
where 1
```

Comment: Habría que tener claro primero a qué corresponde la columna `id` en la tabla `empleado`. Desde el planteamiento de la pregunta yo pienso que hay un error grave de diseño. Si esa columna es la PK de la tabla, usarla para determinar el país sería un grave error.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo mas rapido seria hacerlo de esta manera.

```
SELECT E.id, E.nombre, E.estado, P.id, P.pais FROM empleado E, pais P
```

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor considera leer [answer], editar y explicar el por que de esta solución ayudaría a entenderla mas rápido ya que los aportes que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad

Comment: El problema de hacerlo de esta manera como muestras es que me duplicaria los datos, me añade las columnas pero me duplica todos los datos

Comment: Intenta utilizar la cláusula JOIN para unir dos tablas. Es más legible cuando unes varias tablas a la vez, y es muy útil cuando utilizas más de un tipo de JOIN (LEFT, RIGHT, OUTER , etc)

Answer (score 0):

Porque no creas una nueva columna llamada IdPais

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.empleado ADD IdPais INT NULL;
```

Luego relacionas la tabla empleado con la de pais de la siguiente forma

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.empleado 
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_empleado_pais FOREIGN KEY (IdPais)
      REFERENCES dbo.pais (ID)
```

De ahi asocias a los paises con los empleados

```
  UPDATE empleado SET IdPais = 1 WHERE id = 1
```

y la consulta te quedaría asi:

```
 SELECT E.id,E.nombre,P.id,P.nombre FROM empleado AS E INNER JOIN pais AS P ON P.id = E.IdPais
```

El resultado seria el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Dado que no hay **elementos vinculantes** entre las tablas; no se puede relacionar ni obtener una solución de tipo **relacional**.

Al juntar ambas tablas con una sentencia SQL, te quedaría un resultado que tendría todas las filas de la **tabla 2** por cada una de las filas de la **tabla 1**.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto sería crear una tercera tabla ('EmpleadoOrigen' por ejemplo) y en ella relacionas los registros de la tabla 'Empleado' con la tabla 'Pais'. En esa trabla debe haber una columna para el 'Id' del empleado y otra para el 'Id' del país. Ya despues pudes crear una vista con los datos de esas tablas usando JOIN.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Select E.Id as IdPais, E.Nombre, E.Estado, P.Id as IdPais, P.Pais From EmpleadoOrigen EO Inner Join Empleado E On E.Id=EO.Id Inner Join Pais P On P.Id=EO.Id
```